# Mass, Weight and Inertia

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, inertia

In The Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol-1, it is written

> How hard it is to get a body going is one thing, and how much it weighs is something else. Weight and inertia are proportional, and on earth's surface are often taken to be numerically equal, which causes a certain confusion to the student. *On Mars, weights would be different but the amount of force needed to overcome inertia would be the same*

I've been thinking about the last sentence for a while now but just couldn't figure out what it means.

If two bodies have different weights and the gravitational acceleration is same for both since they are on the same planet, then clearly one body is more *massive* than the other.

Then how is it possible that the amount of force needed to overcome inertia be the same?

Isn't inertia an intrinsic property of a body which is proportional to its mass?

Comment: This seems more of an English question than a physics question: "the same" is supposed to mean that the amount of force needed to overcome inertia is the same *for the same body* on different planets, not the same for two different bodies.

Comment: I think they mean "On Mars, weights would be different _from their respective values on Earth_…", rather "…different from each other".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe he's sayings that the gravitational relationship between objects varies based on the masses at play, but the inertia for a particular mass is invariant regardless.

Like ACuriousMind said i believe the wording is what's confusing you. He means *weights* on Mars would be different (from weights on Earth), but the *inertia* of a given object would be the same in both places.